# Глаголы движения с приставками ПРИ- , У-

Tags: глаголы

Есть ли какое-то правило в использовании глаголов движения после слова КОГДА?

[image]

Например, почему в предложении

> Открывайте окно, когда приходите.

мы используем "приходите"?

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли какое-то правило в использовании глаголов движения после
> слова КОГДА?

Не совсем понимаю, о каком правиле вообще может идти речь. Надо употребить тот глагол, который подходит по смыслу. Ничего более.

> Например, почему в предложении "Открывайте окно, когда приходите" мы
> используем "приходите"?

Даю вашу картинку.

[image: задание]

И отвечаю:
Так по смыслу ничего больше не подходит. "Уходите" означало бы совсем другое.

В вашем задании речь идет не о каком-то особом правиле, а о тренировке использования глаголов с этими приставками, имеющими противоположный смысл.

Но если отвечать более развернуто, в расчете не на студента РКИ (русский как иностранный), а на более академический уровень, то у меня есть претензии к формулировке задания.

Во-первых, не оговорено, что могут быть разные варианты.
Скажем, варианты "отрывайте окно, когда приходите" и "открывайте окно, когда пришли" – оба возможны. Различия есть, но они, скорее, стилистические. Первый вариант предпочтителен в нейтральном стиле, но второй тоже возможен. И так почти по всем вопросам, однозначного выбора тут сделать нельзя.

И во-вторых, глаголами движения в традициях русской академической грамматики называется группа глаголов (числом двенадцать, шестнадцать или даже более – по разным источникам), имеющих парные варианты для движения разового (однонаправленного) и постоянного (циклического, например). Речь о глагольных парах *бежать — бегать, брести — бродить, везти — возить, вести — водить, гнать — гонять, ехать — ездить, идти — ходить, катить — катать, лезть — лазить, лететь — летать, нести — носить, плыть — плавать, ползти — ползать, тащить — таскать*. К этой же группе иногда относят и пары типа *вертеть — вращать* — но это уже не общепринято, отсюда разница в подсчетах.

Доступно о глаголах движения – тут:
https://burupo.com/ru/russian-verbs-of-motion-ru/

Так вот, в предлагаемом учебном задании использование понятия "глаголы движения" представляется совсем неуместным. Оно было бы оправданным, если бы был предопределен выбор между представителями упомянутых пар, но его нету.

Тут приходится выбирать между формами совершенного и несовершенного вида  (причем в заданиях 2, 3, 4, 7, 8 и 9 обе формы возможны) одного-единственного глагола "идти". Но это никак не связано с глаголами движения. И тем более с пристаками "у-" и "при-".

(++)
Возник разговор о выборе нужного глагола – то есть о приставках.

> Я считаю, в номерах 2, 4, 5 можно употребить оба варианта, поэтому
> вопрос и возник.

> я только о приставках.

Думаю, так вопрос стоять не может. **Все задания** (а не только 2, 4 и 5) допускают варианты.

Например:
**Не забудьте сдать книги в библиотеку, когда придете (на работу).**
**Не забудьте сдать книги в библиотеку, когда уйдете (из лаборатории).**

Я просто не вижу, на основании чего тут можно сделать выбор.

Comment: Я считаю, в номерах 2, 4, 5 можно употребить оба варианта, поэтому вопрос и возник.

Comment: @V.V. Эээээ.... Ну во-первых, очень трудно рассуждать о том, что именно стало причиной  трудностей у студента РКИ. Тем более, когда задание плохо сформулировано. А во-вторых, о каких вариантах вы говорите? Если о выборе между совершенным и несовершенным видом, то тут вообще поле непаханое. Все номера в той или иной степени допускают оба варианта, другое дело, что не везде такое по смыслу возможно, ибо может нарушиться естественная последовательность событий Но если вы так вопрос видите, я готов  изложить все свое виденье того, где какая видо-временная форма возможна - и какой у неё смысл.

Comment: Нет, я только о приставках.

Comment: @V.V. а что тут про приставки-то можно сказать? тут во всех вопросах возможны варианты. Выбор между "уйти и придти" только по контексту, нет я все же напишу.

Comment: Вот кошмар для иностранцев, изучающих русский. Спасибо.